# SIR epidemic models on networks

Tags: probability-distributions, graph-theory

I am trying to simulate a SIR epidemic on a network using either R or Python. I have the following question: every model requires a transmission probability between nodes. However, the data that can be easily obtained from papers is Beta: the tranmission **rate**. So, given a value of *Beta*, how can the probability be obtained?

For example: assuming Beta $= 1.2$, how can it be converted to a probability to use in a simulation? Using an exponential distribution and using its formula could be the answer?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the time stepping discrete? If so then you can get the transmission probability by integration over the length of a time step. You could model this with an exponential distribution or with some other distribution.

Comment: That said a suggestion for a query is something like "probabilistic implementation of mass action laws".

Comment: You may be interested in (the source code of) https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.02436

Comment: I read the code, however, it uses as input the probability. It is intended to be a discrete time SIR model. So, given rate beta, would it be wrong to assume p = 1- exp^(-beta), at each time step ?